# Do the sequences converge or diverge?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

1. $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} \cdot \frac{n}{5n+3} $$
   Using Leibniz $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n}= \frac{n}{5n+3}=\frac{1}{5}$ so this is not equal to $0$, divergent
2. $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^6}{3^n} $$
   I guess that $3^{n}$ is growing faster than $n^{6}$ so $a_{n}$ decreases.
3. $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k(k+1)}} $$
   I still have no idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It diverges, since you don't have$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^n\dfrac n{5n+3}=0.$$In fact,$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|(-1)^n\dfrac n{5n+3}\right|=\frac15.$$
2. Since$$\sqrt[n]{\frac{n^6}{3^n}}=\frac{\sqrt[n]n^6}3\to\frac13<1,$$ypur series converges.
3. Since$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{\frac1{\sqrt{k(k+1)}}}{\frac1k}=1$$and the harmonic series diverges, your series diverges too.

Answer (score 1):

1. This is correct.
2. Hint: Try to find a convergent series that majorizes your series.

For that show that for a specific $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have that $n^6\leq 2^n$. This can be done by induction. Then use the geometric series.

Alternativ: This should be able with the quotient criterion as well, but the calculation could be ugly. (Edit: Nevermind, you should try the quotient criterion first, it is pretty simple, if done correctly, but I recommand you try the other calculation as well, since it might be insightfull to solve other problems)

3. Try to find a minorant. Which divergent series do you know?